# How to use DoubleTapListViewHandler with PullToRefresh?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

i use PullToRefreshListView and i want to use it with DoubleTapListViewHandler 
https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler 
but i can't.
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the class from the library and change this line to:

`public class CustomListView extends PullToRefreshListView`

I hope it will work.